# Do I need to clear Volley Request in current activity in order to make another request in other activity?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have two activities using Volley StringRequest. After successful execution of first activity, second activity is started in which I am making request with different URL and parameters. 
This setup is not working as it seems that I am not getting back any response.

Comment: Can you please post your code of the volley requests and the calls?

Comment: @fbwnd I just want to know that can I make StringRequest in another activity after I've made it in the current one.

Comment: Yes its possible. 
Use the requestQueue and Singleton as recommended here:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Comment: A singleton isn't necessary. You just submit the request to the Volley queue. Please [edit] your question to show your code

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree singleton isn't necessary, though this is the recommended way to work with Volley. See: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton

Comment: I know - I use one myself. It just doesn't seem that's the problem